# Matlab: convert a csv char cell to double vector

Tags: matlab

I am having difficulty converting data I am taking from a spectrum analyzer.  It is being placed in a variable that need to be pushed to an excel file to be usable.  The variable that it is placed in is of type char.

```
a=('-2.2748E+01,-2.3454E+00,5.2434E00,.........')
```

How do I convert this to usable data?

Comment: Did you mean to type: `a={'-2.2748E+01','-2.3454E+00','5.2434E00'}`?

Comment: a is a char variable, there are thousands of numbers in it.

Comment: The way you have written it is invalid syntax. Please add the appropriate `'` to indicate what is a string.

Comment: Sorry, I think that I have changed it so that it makes sense.

Comment: What are the `()` in there? Did you mean `{}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `textscan` to easily parse this string out into multiple numbers.

```
a = '-2.2748E+01,-2.3454E+00,5.2434E00';

data = textscan(a, '%f', 'delimiter', ',');
data = data{1};

%  -22.7480
%   -2.3454
%    5.2434
```